# Cultureinfo not applied after build on build server

Tags: c#, winforms, multilingual

Ok, this one is really weird.

We have a main project. Lets call it 'MyApplication'.

To make it multilingual, we added a new project in the solution called 'MyApplication.Languages' which contains all the resx files in different languages.

In our `Main()` we have the following code to switch the CultureInfo:

`Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("nl-NL");`

Obviously, we have a *resx.nl-NL* file and we are referencing this file in our code.

This works perfectly when we execute the code locally, whether it is in Debug or Release mode.
But when the application is build on the build server, the language is never anything other then English. Even when we explicitly set it to "nl-NL" like in the example above.

Does anyone have any idea what could be the issue here?

Comment: maybe dutch is not installed on the build server's operating system, and it falls back to en-US?

Comment: I just checked and Dutch is installed on the build server.

Comment: I'd attempt next to prove by logging that the line where the culture is set, is actually executed, and log back out the effective culture right after. If you want to attract useful answers here, it may be necessary to post a mininal-complete example of the problematic code along with runtime environment specs.

Answer (score 1):

After much trial and error we found out that the multilingual files where not stored in 1 assembly, but in several (one for each language that is configured).
These assemblies are stored in separate folders. In our case *en* and *nl*

During the copy from the artifacts directory, we did not take this into account and therefore, there was no other language then the default English

Hope this helps anyone out there

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and resolved by doing this:

```
private CultureInfo _cultureInfo;

public void SetCurrentUILanguage(CultureInfo cultureInfo)
{
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo; // <- THIS IS VERY IMPORTANTE TO ADD
    CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo; // <- THIS IS VERY IMPORTANTE TO ADD

    _cultureInfo = cultureInfo;
}
```